# Error reproducing demo "You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am getting an error when trying to reproduce a demo that Symfony gives.  You can find it here.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes

I can get the form to work just fine when I include the form inside of the controller but when I make the form its own class I end up getting an error that says.

> You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping 500 Internal
>   Server Error - ParseException

Log returns:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: "You cannot define a
>   sequence item when in a mapping" at
>   /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Parser.php
>   line 81

I can't seem to find where the issue lies.

Task.php File:

```
    <?php

namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $task;

    protected $dueDate;

    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }
    public function setTask($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function getDueDate()
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }
    public function setDueDate(\DateTime $dueDate = null)
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    }
}
```

DefaultController.php:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type\TaskType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();

        $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

TaskType.php:

```
<?php

// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Form/Type/TaskType.php
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('task')
            ->add('dueDate', null, array('mapped' => false))
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        ));
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.  I have tried this setup in multiple files.  It has to be something small.  Its right off of Symfony's site.

---

Edit

---

The only YML file I have is the Validation file i used form their tutorial. 
validation.yml file

```
# Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task:
    properties:
        task:
            - NotBlank: ~
        dueDate:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type: \DateTime
```

Could the problem be that I don't have a yml file that defines an array?

Comment: Your validation should be `- DateTime: ~` rather than `- Type: \DateTime`. That might not be the whole issue though.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue but thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have something in one your yml files like this...

```
stuff:
    thing1: one      // mapping
    thing2: two      // mapping
    thing3: three    // mapping
    - four           // sequence
```

From my guess the error is saying that you can't mix your yaml "mapping" and "sequence" in the same array statement.

so it would need to be either...

```
stuff:
    thing1: one
    thing2: two
    thing3: 
        - four
```

or

```
stuff:
    thing1: one
    thing2: two
    thing3: three
    thing4: four
```

depending on what type of array you were trying to create

Comment: Is there mapping that is located somewhere by default?  I have not created any yml files that have a mapping.  The only files that I have created are the ones that are in the demo I posted at the top.

Comment: You were correct, it was within my validation file.  Its funny because I copy and pasted it but I must have missed something.  Sorry I can't add reputation or I would! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your type class change line `->add('dueDate', null, array('mapped' => false))` to `->add('dueDate', null, array())`

Your `dueDate` filed is indeed mapped

Comment: Still produces the same issue.

Comment: I see now. The error is somewhere in your configuration. Do you use YAML to configure your entity? I believe the error is there.

Comment: I originally had it set to mapped and figured I was missing something so I set mapped to false to see if it would resolve the error and it didn't.  It really does seem like everything should be working.  I have see other comment on the config file but I have nothing set in the config file that would affect what I am doing.

Comment: I just added the config.yml file above

Comment: That's not what I was talking about. Do you have yaml file for the entity?

Comment: No the Entity is a php file.  Its the Task.php file that is above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where the dueDate folder would typically be mapped.  The directory on this thing just gets bigger and bigger and I am sure that there are places in the directory that i haven't visited.  I am interested to solve this issue because since the start of this discussion have created a new project and have it working just fine.  Maybe it was something that happened during the build out?!