# Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException in Behat 3.0 with hash as context parameter

Tags: php, yaml, behat

I try to migrate a Behat 2 project to Behat 3, but I have problems to transform my behat.yml. My behat.yml for Behat 2 was:

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
  context:
    parameters:
      webserver_dir: /Users/bjoerne/Development/WebserverDocuments/wordpress-behat
      webserver_url: http://localhost/wordpress-behat
      install_files:
        wordpress: wordpress-3.9.1-de_DE.zip
        sqlite_integration: sqlite-integration.1.6.3.zip
        disable_google_fonts: disable-google-fonts.1.0.zip
      database_file: database_no_gravatar.sqlite
      selenium_implicit_timeout: 10000
```

I transformed it for Behat 3:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/features ]
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
          - webserver_dir: /Users/bjoerne/Development/WebserverDocuments/wordpress-behat
            webserver_url: http://localhost/wordpress-behat
            install_files:
              wordpress: wordpress-3.9.1-de_DE.zip
              sqlite_integration: sqlite-integration.1.6.3.zip
              disable_google_fonts: disable-google-fonts.1.0.zip
            database_file: database_no_gravatar.sqlite
            selenium_implicit_timeout: 10000
```

When I invoke Behat a Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException is thrown. It seems that the Symfony/Yaml parser can't parse the config. I opened an issue for that: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11019, because it contains a mapping in a sequence in a mapping in a sequence (quite tricky, but that's the Behat 3 way, isn't it?)

I'd like to use a hash as a parameter as it was common in Behat 2. Of cause I could flatten my parameters and just use a normal array as provided by Behat 3. But then I had too many parameters and my code wasn't very clean.

I'd like to know if my transformation from Behat 2 to 3 is correct. Anybody with the same problem? What do you suggest to solve the problem?

**Update**: I tried the following which **doesn't work** either:

1) Without - before 'webserver_dir'

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/features ]
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
          webserver_dir: /Users/bjoerne/Development/WebserverDocuments/wordpress-behat
          webserver_url: http://localhost/wordpress-behat
          install_files:
            wordpress: wordpress-3.9.1-de_DE.zip
            sqlite_integration: sqlite-integration.1.6.3.zip
            disable_google_fonts: disable-google-fonts.1.0.zip
          database_file: database_no_gravatar.sqlite
          selenium_implicit_timeout: 10000
```

Result:

```
Argument 1 passed to FeatureContext::__construct() must be of the type array, none given in /Users/bjoerne/Development/Source/ifttt-wordpress-bridge/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 19
```

It seems that no argument is passed to my constructor

2) move the "webserver_dir" to the next line and indent all the parameters

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/features ]
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
          -
            webserver_dir: /Users/bjoerne/Development/WebserverDocuments/wordpress-behat
            webserver_url: http://localhost/wordpress-behat
            install_files:
              wordpress: wordpress-3.9.1-de_DE.zip
              sqlite_integration: sqlite-integration.1.6.3.zip
              disable_google_fonts: disable-google-fonts.1.0.zip
            database_file: database_no_gravatar.sqlite
            selenium_implicit_timeout: 10000
```

Result is an exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]                                                                            
You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping in "/Users/bjoerne/Development/Source/ifttt-wordpress-bridge/behat.yml"
```

Comment: Why have you added the '-' before 'webserver_dir'? Should work without it. Unless you want to pass all of the parameters as a single array, in which case just move the "webserver_dir" to the next line and indent all the parameters.

Comment: @Jakub Zalas: It doesn't work either. I added my attempts to the post above. Did I exactly what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error reproducing demo "You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750417/error-reproducing-demo-you-cannot-define-a-sequence-item-when-in-a-mapping)